# True console output to character LCD or similar?

Tags: display, lcd

Is it still possible to have text mode output to achieve real console output?

That is, instead of using a virtual console, actually output characters directly to an character LCD screen?

I'd like to see what vi, screen or Emacs looks like on real character LCD.

Comment: Ah let me see. There ain't such thing as "Character" LCD. All English/Chinese/Japanese character LCDs are actually dot matrix LCDs. For the very common 2 rows of 16 English characters, each character is actually formed by usually 5 x 7 dots each of the dots are turned on or off depending on the character you want to display. You might like to skim the driver datasheet to get a rough idea of the 5 x 7 character matrix：Hitachi HD44780U Dot Matrix Liquid Crystal Display Controller/Driver
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf.

Comment: The character driver mentioned above is used in the following character LCDs: https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-16x2-lcd-arduino.html. The same driver can be used to display Chinese/Japan/Korean (CJK) ideographic character or images in bigger, say 128 x 64 dot matrix  LCDs. The big LCD monitors used by PCs are actually “sort of" dot matrix LCD using "more or less" the same theory and operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write direct to the device file of the LCD display. I don't know what it is. You have to look at directory `/dev` for it. For example I have used

```
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'echo "hello world" > /dev/tty1'
```

This will write to the console connected to **tty1**. You will see "hello world" on its display. From a GUI maybe you have to switch to the linux consoles with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, back to the GUI with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I hope it also works on your GUI.